# Select time between two times mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to check if a specific time is between two times (opening and closing time).

The opening and closing times are saved in a database as "start" and "end" related to a weekday id and not to a date.

So my problem is, that I have two different cases first case is that the end-time is bigger than start time like if end=19:00:00 and start=09:00:00

but it also can be end=06:00:00 and start=20:00:00

So what is a performance way to check if a time is between the two times?

My sql looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
      FROM opening
      WHERE weekday_id = :weekday
      AND start <=  :time
      AND end >=  :time
```

Comment: where is `WHERE`? :) try SELECT * FROM opening WHERE weekday_id = :weekday AND (start <= :time AND end >= :time) OR (start >= :time AND end <= :time)

Comment: sorry I changed the original sql statement to the minimum that why there was this mistake

Comment: What is the start and end firlds type?

Comment: So, the question is, is it possible to write it more efficient then `WHERE (start < end AND (:time < end AND :time >= start)) OR (start > end AND (:time >= start OR :time < end))`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is not a great way performance-wise to handle this.  The correct `where` statement is:

```
where (start <= end and :time between start and end) or
      (end < start and :time not between end and start)
```

Of course, you don't have to use `between`, you can expand this out:

```
where (start <= end and :time >= start and :time <= end) or
      (end < start and (:time <= end or :time >= start))
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Was really struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the times are in the same day and you don't know which is the start and which is the end (seems odd) then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM opening
WHERE weekday_id = :weekday
  AND (:time BETWEEN start AND end OR :time BETWEEN end AND start)
```

If the times include the date (datetime) and you know which is which then you just need one between.