# What is the best way to subtract "after-hours" time from a date range to get an accurate "active" time?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I have 2 parallel arrays that contain mysql timestamps.  The first array contains "Start" times, and the second array contains "Stop" times.

**Example**

```
Starts
Array ( [0] => 2014-12-05 12:21:29 [1] => 2014-12-10 07:14:17 [2] => 2014-12-10 12:43:47 [3] => 2014-12-12 07:39:28 [4] => 2014-12-12 08:13:30 ) 

Stops
Array ( [0] => 2014-12-08 08:08:37 [1] => 2014-12-10 10:13:37 [2] => 2014-12-12 07:18:53 [3] => 2014-12-12 08:10:39 [4] => 2014-12-12 08:27:26 )
```

I need to add the total times based off of all the starts and stops in each array, but I also need to subtract all the time that was "after-hours".  This is for reporting purposes.

So let's say that any time after 4pm(16:00) and before 6am(06:00) needs to be removed from the total active time that will be reported.

I already have it subtracting weekend time, but I also need it to remove the "after-hours" time if it occurs after-hours on a weekday.  The checks for weekday/weekend aren't a problem, but figuring out how to check if the time range contains hours that were after business hours is what is stumping me.

Here is how I am subtracting the weekend time:

```
function getWeekendSeconds($starts, $stops){
    $count = 0;
    $secondsToSubtract = 0;
    $secondsInDay = 86400;
    if(count($starts) > count($stops)){
        while(count($starts) != count($stops)){
            array_pop($starts);
        }
    }

    foreach($starts as $start){
        $stop = $stops[$count];

        $startTime = strtotime($start);
        $stopTime = strtotime($stop);

        while($startTime < $stopTime){
            $dayNum = date('N', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $startTime)));
            if($dayNum == 6 or $dayNum == 7){
                $secondsToSubtract += $secondsInDay;
            }
            $startTime = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $startTime) . " +1 day");
        }

        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    return $secondsToSubtract;
}
```

I was thinking of doing something similar to calculate the after-hours time, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Would I just take the start time and add time to it and check it each time to see if it's greater than the business closing time?  Is it simpler than I'm making it?  Is there a mysql solution I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Rizier123, I'm not sure what you're getting at.  Should I be storing timestamps differently?  These have worked for everything else I have done and I pulled them straight from my mysql database.

Comment: You've tagged this `mysql`, but then you say you're working with arrays?

Comment: @Madbreaks, There could be a solution for mysql that I'm not aware of.  If it's doable in mysql, I'm open to suggestions there.

Comment: You'll need to show us what you tried, SQL-wise. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22053717/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4758095/ should be good starting points.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, trying to figure out the sql, but I am not as well versed in mysql so it's taking a while.